# document.getElementById(tableRow_Id) is returning different object names in different browsers. Is this the expected behaviour?

Tags: javascript, html, getelementbyid

I have below snippet.

```
var i = document.getElementById(tableRow_Id);
alert(i);
```

When i run this on different browsers, am getting values like

IE : [object]

FF : [objectHTMLTableRowElement]

I suspect that, because of this only am facing some browser issues.

Can anyone please suggest me?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a syntax error

Your code:

```
var i = document.getElementById(tableRow_Id);
```

Fixed:

```
var i = document.getElementById('tableRow_Id');
```

U forget ''

Comment: element is a reference to an Element object, or null if an element with the specified ID is not in the document.
id is a case-sensitive string representing the unique ID of the element being sought.